# Adding Oracle ASM disk group

Tags: oracle

I am attempting to install an Automatic Storage Management instance on an Oracle 10g install on Windows Vista.  I have tried using manual ASM addition via asmtoolg and also via the interactive DBCA gui.  I have created and stamped 4 2GB partitions, but ASM will not recognize these and allow me to create a disk group.  I'm stuck and cannot move forward with the install.

Answer (score 0):

This would be placed on server Fault as this is not really a programming question. That said, are your partitions set up as basic discs as i believe that dynamic ones are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, Check your rc.local file

add a chown statement so the oracle user has ownership of the disks.

add a chmod statment so the access is 660 (I think this the correct value)

If the oracle user doesn't have access to the drives it won't display them.